# ASCII to Unicode "beautifier"

Tags: text, unicode

I have some ASCII-encoded files containing ascii representations of individual Unicode characters like `...`, `--`, and so on that I'd like to convert to e.g. Unicode ellipsis and en-dash symbols for display purposes. This could be as simple as a simple replace filter over all such mappings (in the right order, to catch things like `---` -> `—` and `--` -> `–`, of course). (note: there are more than just those)

Does there exist a database of all such conversions somewhere? I assume the inverse must exist somehow to be able to gracefully convert unicode to plaintext whenever possible, e.g. `…` -> `...`.

It doesn't have to be extremely accurate or anything as long as the conversion is appropriate in most cases and makes sense. The output will be just be displayed to the user and won't be further processed. I could just compile a list myself as I go but it would be nice to save time and avoid duplicating effort if it has already been done.

Thanks!

Comment: The Unicode database has a lot of these compatibility mappings (e.g., `…` → `...`), but they are not "plaintext" and reversing them usually a bad idea. Do you want to replace `p.m.` with `㏘`, or `HP` with `㏋`?

Comment: You're probably looking for something like [SmartyPants](http://daringfireball.net/projects/smartypants/).

Comment: @一二三 SmartyPants looks like it does what I want, thanks! Can you add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comprehensive list isn't a very good idea as there are a lot of Unicode characters that exist for compatibility, or are poorly supported (see my comment). Instead, you probably want to use a curated list/library like [SmartyPants](http://daringfireball.net/projects/smartypants/) (ports/alternatives can be found for most other languages).